# Center Placeholder Text in Safari

Tags: css

```
#po_user_table input[type="text"]{
    text-align: center;
    width: 98%;
}
```

That is my CSS.  I've tried:
    text-align: -webkit-center;

I've tried:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
text-align: center
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder, ::-webkit-input-placeholder,
textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder
{ 
text-align:center; 
}
```

But not matter what I do, my input fields in safari are all left justified instead of centered.  The first example works in IE, Chrome, FF, Opera.  Just in Safari it is not centered.

What can I do?

Comment: What version of Safari are you testing? On what platform? Mobile? The following works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/zswopqrx/ (Safari on Mac running OS X 10.9.5)

Comment: It is Safari 5.1.7 on a Windows 7 Desktop.  Not mobile.  I tried what obviously works for you but its not working in my code so something else must be making it not be center, but even using the web developer tools in safari I cant find anything bad.  i'll just have to keep trying till I figure it out.

Comment: Ah, I see. [And yes, it looks like Windows + Safari has issues with styling the placeholder attribute.](http://blog.ajcw.com/2011/02/styling-the-html5-placeholder/) Is supporting Safari on Windows crucial?

Comment: Well... probably not that crucial.  I'll probably work on it some more but not put that much more time into it.  Chances are people using windows wont be using Safari and the few that are, the placeholder not being centered wont be a game changer.  I just hate when things don't work hehe.

Comment: Haha, I hear you man! I was going to say - if it was crucial, you could fall back to a JavaScript solution where you overlay a "placeholder" element above your input (which is centered)...but for a discontinued browser from 2012, I don't know if it's worth it :) (I was looking for marketshare, but couldn't find that data). I honestly applaud your effort though, it's a sign of a great developer (one with that attention to detail)